# React not redirecting as intended when A function is called in the Routes route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a login and logout system for a react project of mine. I have a navbar setup and I am using `react-redirect-dom` to create links and redirect links to different pages in order to manage the login system.

In the current project, I have a route that does the processing for the login in the login component. I have another link that processes the signup within the signup component.

For the logout, If a user is logged in and they use the `/logout` endpoint, I want it to immediately call the `handleLogout` function and log the user out and reroute to the `/` endpoint

Here is the code I have and the error:

```
function App() {

  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState('')

  function handleLogout() {
    console.log('handle logout')
    axios.post('/api/auth/logout', {
      "username":currentUser.username,
      "password":currentUser.password,
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data.data)
      setCurrentUser(data.data)
      setLoggedIn(false)
      return(<Navigate to='/' />)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <ContentContext value={contentContextValue}> */}
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={loggedIn ? <Feed/> : <Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser}/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/signup" element={<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser}/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/logout" element={loggedIn ? () => {handleLogout()} : <Login/>}/>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter> 
      {/* </ContentContext> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

**************** UPDATE ***********************

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Logout(props) {
  const {
    handleLogout
  } = props

  const Logout = ({ handleLogout }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    React.useEffect(() => {
      handleLogout();
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }, []);
  
    return null;
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 the `Route` components take an `element` prop that takes ***only*** a `ReactElement`, a.k.a. JSX. Passing a function here is invalid, as the warning points out.

Refactor your logout logic into a component in a mounting `useEffect` hook. Invoke the passed `handleLogout` function and then imperatively redirect to the home `"/"` path.

```
const Logout = ({ handleLogout }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleLogout();
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }, []);

  return null;
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route
    path="/"
    element={loggedIn
      ? <Feed />
      : <Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />
    }
  />
  <Route
    path="/login"
    element={<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/signup"
    element={<Login setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn} setCurrentUser={setCurrentUser} />}
  />
  <Route
    path="/logout"
    element={loggedIn
      ? <Logout handleLogout={handleLogout} />
      : <Login />
    }
  />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Okay so what you are saying is to create a logout component and add the Logout method you added into the logout component. Then when logout is clicked it will call the handleLogout and then redirect to the ```/```

Comment: @omarjandali Affirmative. This is because the `element` prop takes only valid JSX as a value. `navigate` is a void function, it doesn't return any JSX to render.

Comment: Okay, so would the logout component look like what I am adding to the original quesiton?? or is the ```Logout``` component just the block you have??

Comment: @omarjandali Mine. Or yours if you unnest the `Logout` component from the `Logout` component and use that instead.